# Tracking button clicks with Google Analytics and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track clicks of the call to action button (**#mc-embedded-subscribe**) on the footer of this article with Google Analytics and JavaScript: https://danielpuiatti.com/html-basics-syntax-semantics-and-best-practices/

Here is my code, it doesn't seem to register in Google Analytics.

```
var emailListSubscribeFooterButton = document.querySelector("#mc-embedded-subscribe");
emailListSubscribeFooterButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'button',
        eventAction: 'click',
        eventLabel: event.target.href,
        transport: 'beacon'
      });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct, are sure to use `ga` (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) snippet instead `gtag` (https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/snippet) snippet?